# Not know exception with firebase filters

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**This code:**

```
var query: Query = store.collection(COLLECTION_USERS)
        query = query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("age", filter.startAge).whereLessThanOrEqualTo("age", filter.endAge)
        query = query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("start_date", filter.startDate).whereLessThanOrEqualTo("end_date", filter.endDate)
        query = query.whereEqualTo("sex", filter.sex)
        return query.get()
```

throw exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All where filters other than whereEqualTo() must be on the same field. But you have filters on 'age' and 'start_date'` how to fix?

Answer (score 4):

[Official documentation of Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) says that range filters on different fields are `forbidden`. So Firestore allows to chain multiple `where()` methods to create more specific queries but only on the same field.

To achieve what you want, you need to query your database twice, once for each fiter because you cannot use both methods in the same query.

Another way to make it happen would be to store a special flag that might fit the query, although in real world applications it will almost impossible to store every single way a user might query the data.

Comment: I was writing the same answer, it is restricted to query multiple where on different fields.